# Unknown server tag cc1: ToolkitScriptManager

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajaxcontrols and in that all controls are working well But I had not found any of the control named as `ToolkitScriptManager` so I had just copied this tag in .html page.

What shall I do?
The version of framework in hosting server is 2.

My Web.config file is:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" TagPrefix="cc1"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0" newVersion="1.0.61025.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Star
        {
            background-image: url(images/Star.gif);
            height: 17px;
            width: 17px;
        }
        .WaitingStar
        {
            background-image: url(images/WaitingStar.gif);
            height: 17px;
            width: 17px;
        }
        .FilledStar
        {
            background-image: url(images/FilledStar.gif);
            height: 17px;
            width: 17px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
        StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
        FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
    </cc1:Rating>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblRatingStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to register your user control on the page first as shown here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: thanks but I've the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the **ajaxToolkit** prefix.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

same for **Rating** control.

Answer (score 13):

For newer versions of Ajax tool kit you have to use the asp script manager:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error message at a customer site and noticed the `web.config` file was saved as a `web.config.txt` file. Reverting the file to a `web.config` file resolved this issue.

I am not saying everyone with the issue will have the same problem, but the permissions and settings may not allow a non developer to notice this uncommon issue to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of causes like not having the control registered, etc.
But the thing that solved my issue was.......

It's because the ToolkitScriptManager control instance is not present in the designer.cs file.
First check if the ajaxControlToolkit instance is present in designer.cs file and if not, Paste below code manually in the designer.cs file and it should fix it

```
    /// <summary>
    /// SMMain control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager SMMain;
```